# Jquery submit a form from a jquery tab

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write a simple jquery tab submit logic for a form that is isn't another rendered view

The code I am using is

```
$(function () {
    $(".save").on("click", function () {
        var href = $(this).closest(".contents").find(".ui-tabs-selected").attr("href");
        debugger;
        $(href).find("form").submit();
    });
});
```

now when I click this my href variable is undefined, any reasons why? here is my HTML also

```
<section id="page-content">
<div class="contents">
    <div class="workspace-column">
        <div class="title">@Model.Name</div>
        <div class="function-bar">
                <a href="#" class="save">Save</a>
            </div>
        <div>
            <div class="tab-set">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Information", "Update", new { id = Model.Id})">Update</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Profile", "Update", new { id = Model.Id})">Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

P.S. this is a cshtml file I am using with MVC.

Update ---

here is a picture of the generated HTML
[image]

Comment: Could you show the generated html instead of the razor file ? Here, I don't see any element with an `.ui-tabs-selected` class...

Comment: There is no element exists named `.ui-tabs-selected` in your provided markup!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak that is because Jquery tabs adds that to the list

Comment: @Canvas Copy and paste that code here!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak View the image I just uploaded

Comment: where is your ".save" in image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui-tabs-selected will be on the **li** tags rather than the <**a**> tag won't it?  So you need and extra jquery command to get the <**a**> e.g.:

```
var href = $(this)
    .closest(".contents")
    .find(".ui-tabs-selected a")
    .attr("href");
```

I was also recommend using single quotes in your href for Information, Profile etc.

Comment: Yep that works just fine, cheers for that, it makes sense, why on earth i didn't check the a tag :D

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try: 
   You have to go deep through the `DOM` as you're not considering `<a>`  tag which is having `href` attribute like following

```
 var href = $(this).closest(".contents").find(".tab-set")
           .find('a').attr("href"); //.tab-set is just an example you can use ui-tabs-selected
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6s2G8/)